# How to access flask app running on remote Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: flask, jupyter-notebook

So recently I logged in into a remote jupyter notebook server (something like `http://XX.XXX.XX.XXX:YYYY/tree`) with a given password for an organization using Chrome.

I had to upload a flask app on the jupyter notebook server. I did the upload and started the flask app, it showed me `Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)`, just like it would on my local jupyter notebook environment. Now I want to access the app. While running the app from my local jupyter notebook environment, I used to just go to `127.0.0.1:5000` and it would work. How do I access the app now? I learned something about SSH and PuTTY but I am not sure what it really is. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'd ask  irst whoever gave you the password to access the remote server.

Answer (score 2):

Use flask_ngrok to 'tunnel' or 'port-forward' your port 5000 to public internet.

Reference: https://pypi.org/project/flask-ngrok/

```
try: 
    import flask_ngrok
    is_dependency_installed = True
except ImportError:
    is_dependency_installed = False

if not is_dependency_installed:
    !pip install flask==0.12.2
    !pip install flask-ngrok
    # note: flask version must be 0.12.2 in order to work with flask_ngrok

    is_dependency_installed = True
```

Then, before running your app (before calling `app.run()`), call `flask_ngrok.run_with_ngrok(app)`
Example:

```
from flask_ngrok import run_with_ngrok
run_with_ngrok(app)
app.run()
```

Output:

```
INFO:werkzeug: * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Running on http://987fd65a.ngrok.io
 * Traffic stats available on http://127.0.0.1:4040
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [11/Dec/2019 06:12:26] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [11/Dec/2019 06:12:27] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```